# Number of additions / multiplications from symbolic expression in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have an algorithm that generates symbolic expressions, which consist out of a lot of additions and multiplications. For evaluating the performance, I want to count the number of additions and multiplications.

Right now, I convert the symbolic expression into a string and search this string for occurrences of the characters '+' or '*'. This works but is very slow.

Is there a way to access the internal representations of a symbolic expression in Matlab in order to extract information like this?

```
symbolicExpressionStr = char(symbolicExpression)
numOfAdditions = sum(symbolicExpressionStr == '+') + length(strfind(symbolicExpressionStr , '- '));
numOfMultiplications = sum(symbolicExpressionStr == '*' | symbolicExpressionStr == '/');
```

Comment: When you say "This is very slow", how slow are you meaning? Because a logical comparison like that should be pretty pacey...

Comment: Which part is slow? Converting to char or searching for `+` and `*`?